# Is there a fix for my string extraction code?

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops, extract

I am trying to extract a substring which has a random position from different strings. The substing is not a fixed value but a "T" and then four numberals e.g. T6000.

[image: Please see this image.]

As you can see in this image there are a number of machines names where most of them contain a T number. The T number is also different in almost all of the cases. The column of the machines names is "E".  First number (T6000) is in E16, last is in E25.

Using my code:

```
For Ipattern = 16 To NumofMachines + 15 Step 1
    TNUMcell = Dsht.Range("E" & Ipattern).Value
    'Verify if string contains a Tnum
    TNUMLikeBoolean = TNUMcell Like "*T###*"

    If TNUMLikeBoolean = True Then
        Do Until TNUMdone = True
            TNUMchar1 = InStr(TNUMcell, "T") + 1
                TNUMcharV = Mid(TNUMcell, TNUMchar1)
                TNUMchecknum = IsNumeric(TNUMcharV)
                    If TNUMchecknum = True Then
                        Dsht.Range("F" & Ipattern).Value = "T" & Mid(TNUMcell, TNUMchar1, 5)
                        TNUMdone = True
                    End If
        Loop
    Else
        Dsht.Range("F" & Ipattern).Value = "NO T"
    End If
Next Ipattern
```

It only fills in the first and the last cell of the 'export' range (F16:F25).

I have been searching for an answer quite some time. As I am (obviously) *not* a VBA expert.

**What am I doing wrong? Why is not filling in the other values?**

Thanks,
Wouter J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim r As Range, i As Long, c As Long

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "T\d{4}"

    For Each r In Range("E16", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        c = 6
        If .Test(r.Value) Then
            For i = 0 To .Execute(r.Value).Count - 1
                Cells(r.Row, c).Value = .Execute(r.Value)(i)
                c = c + 1
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :) Nice one.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Damn that worked like a charm. Thanks alot!!. If you have the time could you elaborate a little how that code thinks and works? I am just trying to learn here :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I am not so good at explaining. May be someone helps you at this point. Sorry as English is not my native language.

Comment: Regular expressions is a world of its own which requires careful study, but in outline it is pattern matching, in this case "T" followed by 4 digits (\d{4}).

Comment: The pattern used means to start with the letter "T" followed by 4 numbers then loop through each cell in your range and begins to extract the strings that match the pattern. The results would be put at column 6 and if there are more results the variable c would be increased by 1 each time then don't forget to reset c to 6 after manipulating each cell. That's all

Comment: I cant upvote your comments yet but I would If I could. Thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your variable `TNUMdone`.

This is set to `True` on the first iteration of the loop and then never again set to `False`, so this code after `Do Until TNUMdone = True` never runs again.

At the start of your loop, just set `TNUMdone` to `False` and it should work:

```
For Ipattern = 16 To NumofMachines + 15 Step 1
    TNUMdone = False
    TNUMcell = Dsht.Range("E" & Ipattern).Value
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I have adjusted my formula accordingly and it now shows the second but then crashes. could it be because that t number contains more than one T? How can I work around that?